# Using array.push inside of another array yields undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I ran into a problem when trying to define an array inside of Fire array (seen in code).

I used console.log() to output array length which is inside of my Fire[] array (as a debug) but got an error saying that said array was undefined. Here's my code:

```js
var Fire = [];

var fire = function FireGen()
{
    this.particle = [];
    var part = function Particle()
    {
    };
    this.particle.push(part);
};
Fire.push(fire);

console.log(Fire.particle.length); //Outputs undefined
```

I'm quite new when it comes to object and array usage in JavaScript. I would appreciate if someone could explain why my array is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, `Fire` is an array, so to access properties of the first element from that array, you need to use `Fire[0]...`. However, there are a few other problems with your code that also need to be fixed.

Your `FireGen` and `Particle` functions appear to be defined as constructor functions (you use `this` in the function body). So you should call these functions with the [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) operator, e.g. `new FireGen()`. Once you make this change, you should probably rearrange your code so that `x` and `y` are passed in as arguments and you only define each function once.

For example:

```js
var Fire = [];
function FireGen(x, y)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.particle = [];
    this.particle.push(new Particle(x, y));
};
function Particle(x, y)
{
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
};

function spawnFire(event)
{
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;
    Fire.push(new FireGen(x, y));

    console.log(Fire[0].particle.length); //Outputs undefined
}

document.addEventListener('click', spawnFire);
```

Answer (score 1):

By doing `push(part)` and `push(fire)`, you're pushing function definitions.

For these to behave as classes, use the  [**`new` operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new). (ie `push(new part)` and `push(new fire)`.

Additionally, `Fire` is an array so you'll need to specify an index (eg `Fire[0]` for the first item in the array).

```js
var Fire = [];

var fire = function FireGen()
{
    this.particle = [];
    var part = function Particle()
    {
    };
    this.particle.push(new part);
};
Fire.push(new fire);

console.log(Fire[0].particle.length);
```

Comment: @GytisDokšas Glad to have helped. That said, take a gander at [p.s.w.g's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54355511/2026606). His implementation is extensible and - in my personal opinion - the proper way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

You're defining functions, which are never executed, and pushing those functions into an array. The array contains a function, which doesn't have a `particle` property.

Odds are you're trying to do something like this:

```js
var Fire = [];

var fire = {
  particle: [
    {
      part: { /* ... */ }
    }
  ]
}

Fire.push(fire);

console.log(Fire[0].particle.length); //Outputs 1
```